# Post method giving null parameters

Tags: html, jsp

I have to upload a file to a specific folder.Here is the jsp page which receives the parameters and saves them.

xyz.jsp

```
    <%@page import="filepack.FileInfo"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"
    contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
    <body>


     <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="filepack.FileInfo" scope="request" />
     <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="*"/>
     <%@include file="upload.jsp" %>

    <%

    String uid = session.getAttribute("userId")+"";

     String filetype=obj.getFiletype();
    String fileName = uploadFile(application.getRealPath("/uploads")  + "/" + uid +"/"+filetype,"", request);
    boolean status = obj.saveFileInfo(fileName,uid); 
    if(status==true)
        response.sendRedirect("uploadfiles.jsp?msg=File Saved&filtype="+filetype);
    else
        response.sendRedirect("uploadfiles.jsp?msg=File Not Saved");
    %>
```

the file cannot be saved because the filetype parameter is null and so are other parameters except for the fileName parameter.

I could not figure out why all parameters except fileName are null.Please help me.

P.S:-when I use get method all parameters are received but the fileName parameter is null.

here is FileInfo.java

```
package filepack;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class FileInfo {

int fileid;
Date filedate;
String fileName;
String filetype;
String filedesc;
String sender;
String receiver;
String sendmode;
String sendstatus;
String receivestatus;



 public  boolean saveMyFileInfo(String fname,String userid)
{
    FileInfo f=new FileInfo();
    java.util.Date todayDate1 = new java.util.Date();
     java.sql.Date todayDate = new java.sql.Date(todayDate1.getTime());
     filedate=todayDate;
     int n=0;
     try
     {
    Connection cn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("insert into myfileinfo(fileid,filedate,filename,filetype,filedesc,userid) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    String sql="select nvl(max(fileid),0)+1 from myfileinfo";
    fileid=f.nextID(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, fileid);
    ps.setDate(2,filedate);
    ps.setString(3, fname);
    ps.setString(4,filetype);
    ps.setString(5,filedesc);
    ps.setString(6,userid);
    n = ps.executeUpdate();
    closeConnection(null, ps, cn);
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {

     }

    return n == 1;

}

 public  int saveFileInfo(String fname) throws Exception
{
    Connection cn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("Insert Into fileinfo(fileid,filename) values (?,?)");
    String sql="select nvl(max(fileid),0)+1 from fileinfo";
    fileid=nextID(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, fileid);
    ps.setString(2, fname);
    int n = ps.executeUpdate();
    closeConnection(null, ps, cn);

    if (n == 1) {
        return fileid;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}



 public int nextID(String sql)
{
    int nid=0;
    try
    {
    Connection cn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
        nid = rs.getInt(1);
         closeConnection(null, ps, cn);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    return nid;
}








public int getFileid() {
    return fileid;
}

public void setFileid(int fileid) {
    this.fileid = fileid;
}

//....
```

}

Comment: when you are uploading files (i.e. `enctype='multipart/form-data'`) `request.getParameter()` will always return `null`. You have to either use something like Apache Commons File Upload or `request.getPart()` for *all* the parameters not just the file. Also, `<jsp:useBean` is really obsolete by now, so you shouldn't be using that.

Comment: Commons File Upload doesn't helped me.

Comment: the library `filepack.FileInfo` you are already using doesn't have a way to get the other parameters besides the file?